# How do get good result with multiple str_split text characters lines

Tags: php, string, split

In my php code below am trying to fetch a multiple text character from database and  `str_split`  each result output. add `USED`  to the end line of each output and output remaining characters also i have tried:

```
 require("init.php"); 
 echo "<form action='reg.php' method='post'>
            <b>booking code:</b><br />
            <input type='text' name='book' size='17' /> 
            <input type='submit' name='login' maxlength='2' size='2' value='PRINT OUT' />
        </form>"; 

  if(isset($_POST["login"]))
  { 
      $book = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["book"]); 
      $sql = "SELECT `item_name` , `quantity` FROM `books` WHERE `book`='$book'"; $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
      while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
        $d[] = $row1["item_name"]; 
        $v[] = $row1["quantity"]; 
        foreach($d as $r); 
        foreach($v as $ro); 
        $get = array(0 => array("yes" => $r, "no" => $ro)); 
        foreach ($get as $item) { 
           $getd = $item["yes"]; 
        } 
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM promo WHERE code='$getd' LIMIT 1"); 
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) { 
           $type = $row["name"]; 
           $code = $row["recharge"]; 
           $deta = $row["details"]; 
           $logo = $row["logo"]; 
           $price = $row["price"]; 
           if(preg_match('/(xyz)/i', $type)) $type = "20"; 
           if(preg_match('/(log)/i', $type)) $type = "16"; 
        } 
        $id = $item["no"];  
        $result = str_split($code, $type); 
        $a = ""; 
        $c = "";
for($b = 0; $b<$id; $b++)
  {
    $a .= $result[$b];
}
$b = "USED";
for($bn = $id; $bn<sizeof($result); $bn++){
           $c .= $result[$bn];
        }
    echo $a.$b.$c;
}
}
}
```

and all my result output with code is unknow am saying all result all complecated result output thanks for your time and impact in my solutions

Comment: Your code is a mess, please update your question to include proper code example

Comment: @flying Please see now i have just editted

Comment: Can you please provide example of desired and actual responses?

Comment: Also what is `foreach($d as $r); foreach($v as $ro); ` stays for? I can't imagine any practical meaning of such construction

Comment: I just want to add `USED` to each text end line of str_split characters from the database result an output remaining  characters from result example
`foofoofoo` #database result
`foofUSEDoofoo` #after split
`oofoo` #remaing result
thanks for your understanding

Comment: You have no "USED" anywhere in your code. Does it mean that you have pasted wrong code example?

Comment: I have no idea or better way of it was just trying to use foreach to handle each row result so it could have and array for better result

Comment: I just edited hope is crean now thanks for your returns

Comment: Sorry, I still have no idea what is your question is about...

Comment: Ok Thanks so much for your impact any way! is presure to type you do have somthing email contact so put  it in a better way via to you then making question here?

Comment: Check on the first `while` loop. It seems it would need to be closed before starting to use the arrays used in the `foreach` statements.